# Fix slivers (Holes) between polygons ( generated after removing spikes)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, slivers, holes

I am trying to fix topological errors in [this Shapefile](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_de_setores_censitarios__divisoes_intramunicipais/censo_2010/setores_censitarios_shp/ba/ba_setores_censitarios.zip) of small areas of a state (Bahia) in Brazil. After applying prepair and PPrepair, the resulting shapefile has some spikes:

[image]

It looks like a line from far, but when we zoom in we can see that the spike has some area:

[image]

Then I removed the spikes with a Postgis buffer function:

```
SELECT geom,
  ST_Buffer(  ST_Buffer(  ST_Buffer(geom,0.00001, 'join=mitre'),-0.00002,                           
  'join=mitre'),0.00001, 'join=mitre') AS geom_spike_removed
  FROM repaired_polygons;
```

resulting in this, (I overlayed the layer) and got some holes between polygons:

[image]

How do I remove the slivers so that the empty area is attributed to the nearest polygon?

The spike and subsequent sliver is about 0.071mm in width.

Comment: please make this more reproducible by adiing links to the original file, pprepair, the spike removal function in Postgis, related questions here

Comment: also, It could be nice if you could add the file that contains the spikes (output from pprpair) and the id of the polygon with the spikes

Comment: @LucasMation that's not likely feasible if the data cannot be shared

Comment: Jader - how many polygons do you have to fix? QGIS has the Topology Checker plugin that you can use to determine how many issues you might have... could be a manual fix though

Comment: @DPSSpatial, the data is public

Comment: there are 24000~ polygons, @DPSSpatial I'm not sure how many of them has this error, then I need to correct for other states, 27 in total. I need a consistent methodology to propose the data update. ps: added the source.

Comment: @LucasMation nice in this case, but doesn't always need to be a requirement.

Comment: @JaderMartins yikes!!! I see what you're doing... is this possibly an issue for the plugin creators?

Comment: Yeah, an Issue was already created, but the developers didnt solve yet, but I think there are other methods to solve this in an automatic way.

Comment: @JaderMartins, please add the rest of the references, id, code used in postgis

Comment: ST_Snap can offer some help but not always if adjacent polygons do not share same vertices. You may need to use some special topology tools. OpenJUMP Plus for example has quite good set of topology tools.

Comment: @JaderMartins, have you tryied [normalize_geometry](https://gasparesganga.com/labs/postgis-normalize-geometry/) the  instead of 3 cunterbalancing ST_Buffer s (to remove the spikes)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you got the data, but it's wrong, see the picture.[image]
The errors are different, for example: self-intersections, absence of interfacing of polygons with each other, etc. As of 24139 only 20 broken, my suggestion is the following, 1) convert the multipolygons to polygons, 2) Use the function ST_SnapToGrid PostGIS, with a tolerance of 3) Remove the broken polygons that create the outer polygon and cut out its "proper polygon" :-), and add to your layer...such actions will allow you to bring your data in order...By the way, for some reason QGIS does not show me problems with your data, although in fact they are...